# Can't ssh with key after upgrade/new install of 18.04 server

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, openssh

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on both desktop and server. Trying to login as user (not root) to server with ssh fails with "Permission denied (publickey)". SSH worked before with server being 16.04, but not now after fresh install. I would love to post the output with `ssh -vvv` option but I get the "This looks like spam" objection here in Askubuntu. When I edit `sshd_config` to allow passwords I can login that way.

Comment: Upload the output of `ssh -vvv` to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and include a link to it in your question

Comment: When I set StrictModes to no it works, but I can't work out what permissions I should set. I set .ssh to 700 on both client and host machine, but no go.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Double checking the permissions in my home directory on the host showed I had it writable by my group. My bad.

Comment: I solved it by changing the permissions from the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` file to 700.